# Extracting gene sequences from FASTA File?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have the following code that reads a FASTA file with 10 gene sequences and return each sequences as a matrix.
However the code seems to be missing on the very last sequence and I wonder why?

`````
file=open('/Users/vivianspro/Downloads/rosalind_cons (5).txt', 'r')
line=file.readline()

strings = []
sequence=''
while line:
    #line=line.rstrip('\n')
    line = line.strip() #empty () automatically strips the \n
    if '>' in line:
        if sequence != "":
            strings.append(sequence)
            sequence = ""
        #sequence=line
    else:
        sequence+=line
    line=file.readline()
for s in strings:
    print(s)

Motifs = []
for seq in strings:
    Motifs.append(list(seq))

#make every symbol into an element in the list separated by ,
for s in Motifs:
    print(s) ````
`````

Comment: You only append to strings if '>' in line. Can we see some example data?

Comment: @AustinHastings That's how FASTA is formatted. It's easy to see some samples by looking up the format e.g. on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You only append to `strings` when you see a new `>` but there isn't one after the last sequence.

Here is a refactoring which will hopefully also be somewhat more idiomatic.

```
strings = []
sequence=''

with open('/Users/vivianspro/Downloads/rosalind_cons (5).txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if sequence != "":
                strings.append(sequence)
            sequence = ""
        else:
            sequence+=line
    # After the last iteration, append once more if we have something to append
    if sequence:
        strings.append(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since FASTA files contain the data in such a format:

```
>ID1
seq_1
>ID2
seq_2
...
```

According to your code, if your line contains a `>` only then you try to append the sequence. That means, you are adding the sequence for ID_1 when you are iterating for ID_2.

To resolve this, you can do something like this:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if '>' in line: # Line 1
        line = file.readline().strip()
        # print(line)
        strings.append(line)
```

This above example uses the fact that in a FASTA file, the sequence comes directly after the ID, which contains the `>` character (you can change Line 1, so that it just checks for the first char, `line[0] == ">"`).